# Accessing elements of a 2-D ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have declared a 2-D arrayList as follows-

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

The output of arrayList is something like this-

[[1,a],[2,b],[3,c],......]
I want to know is there a way to save the two columns separately in different arrays? All numbers in one array and all letters in a different array.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you provide an example of the operation you are trying to achieve with a 2D array as an example?

Comment: Array? Columns? I see an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s.

Comment: I hope you know that 2D-Array means a structure similar to an Excel sheet. It is not possible to save that as two distinct arrays easily (you could but you would need to track the width and height yourself). What is your issue with handling your boxed list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have two `ArrayList`s.

```
ArrayList<Integer>   numbers = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can have a method that simultaneously add items to both:

```
public void add(Integer number, Character letter) {

    numbers.add(number);
    letters.add(letter);
}
```

Now since you want to sort the lists according to the numbers, and also want the letters to be sorted corresponding to the numbers, so instead of creating 2 separate arrays or arraylists, you can use the features of OO, i.e. `Encapsulation`:

```
// Simply create a class that will store the number and the letter
public class Capsule {

    private int number;
    private char letter;

    // Create a constructor to initialise the variables 
    public Capsule(int number, char letter) {

        this.number = number;
        this.letter = letter;
    }



    // Create getters to retrieve their values
    public int getNumber() {

        return number;
    } 

    public char getLetter() {

        return letter;
    }
}
```

Now in your main,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an arraylist of Capsule class' objects
    ArrayList<Capsule> capsules = new ArrayList<>();


    // Create any number of capsule objects in an unsorted manner
    Capsule cap1 = new Capsule(1, 'a');
    Capsule cap3 = new Capsule(3, 'c');
    Capsule cap2 = new Capsule(2, 'b');

    // Add them all to arraylist
    capsules.add(cap1);
    capsules.add(cap3);
    capsules.add(cap2);

    // Implement your sorting algorithm here...
    // instead of sorting the numbers, sort the capsule objects
    // For example you want to implement bubble sort...
    for(int i = 0; i < capsules.size() - 1; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < capsules.size() - i - 1; j++) {

            if(capsules.get(d) > capsules.get(d + 1)) {

                Capsule temp = capsules.get(d);
                capsules.set(d, capsules.get(d + 1));
                capsules.set(d + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }


    // Finally print the results 
    for(int i = 0; i < capsules.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("["+capsules.get(i).getNumber()+", "+capsules.get(i).getLetter()+"]");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am sorting the arrayList based on the value of the integers and later I just want the characters in a sorted manner. So I can't start off with two different arrays.

Comment: Edited according to your problem. You just dont need to use two separate arrays for your problem at all